# What could have been the sentences I was thinking about?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

I have just thought about an interesting problem in classical propositional logic to propose at this site, but lost my notes...  I do recall, however, that the problem involved a particular contingent sentence with three atomic variables, $p$, $q$ and $r$. This first sentence contained exactly two occurrences of connectives, both binary. I am positive that at least one of those connectives was an implication having one of the three aforementioned variables as antecedent.

**Question 1.**  Assuming that the previous information is sufficient to *semantically characterize* the forgotten sentence, can you determine what was its other connective, as well as the possible logical forms that my sentence could have had?

Now, another thing I do recall is that the problem that I had created consisted in checking that the first sentence above is *semantically equivalent* to a second sentence, written with the same variables and containing the same connectives as the first sentence, but with one extra implication.

**Question 2.** What could have been this second sentence?  Justify.

---

The following extra considerations should be unnecessary to solve the problem:

> **Word of warning.**
>  
>   While one must *not* disconsider any information from the above statement when looking for a solution, one should also not read more than what is written. In particular: 
>  
>  (1) Nowhere in the statement of the problem is to be found a claim about the first (or the second) sentence being "syntactically unique". In fact, there is obviously no way, for instance, of avoiding permutation of the variables in a given solution. But there might clearly be many other *structurally different* sentences (belonging to the same equivalence class!) that solve **Question 1**. The task is to identify such sentences (preferably without just guessing).
>  
>  (2) In the statement of the problem, a sentence is supposed to be "semantically characterized" when it is characterized *up to logical equivalence* --- so, again, you had better think first about what is happening at the level of the quotient algebra, and consider next the syntactic restrictions imposed by the statement of the problem.
>  
>  
> **Hint.**
>  
> The *assumption* made in **Question 1** is integral part of the statement, and in fact essential to the existence of a well-determined solution!

Comment: I would have thought "formal logic" or something would be more suitable. I think Maths is used generally more for things like "use these numbers and operators to do this". More what most people would think of as maths than university level people...

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the feedback. I have now also added the tag `logic`, because of the syntactical aspects of the problem. Boolean Algebras are part of `math`, anyway. I believe the problem is not easy to solve, but might be worth a try.

Comment: @J Marcos That's funny.. Really, me solve this? I can probably point out 4 words in that I don't get and multiple sentences I don't understand, I'd never be able to solve this.

Comment: @warspyking As a token of support for you, I can at least confirm that the problem is indeed not easy to solve... Now, as for not understanding the statement, haven't you said before that you did find see any troubles in the way it was formulated?

Comment: I do not understand the question itself, what the heck is a connective?

Comment: @warspyking [Connectives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective) are syntactical counterpart of operators. This is standard terminology in [Logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic). In [Universal Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra) they are called *function symbols*. In Linguistics they provide particular examples of [conjunctions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar)). The very first line in the statement of the problem already says that it presupposes familiarity with propositional logic!

Comment: @J Marcos You lost me... There's really no point in attempting to teach me this.

Comment: @JMarcos I think many people on this site have a hard time grasping the concept - maybe you could help us understand the question better by providing an example solution (like an easy first try, which statisfies some of the requirements of the question, but not all of them) - and explain why this exampe solution is wrong?

Comment: For example - if your question was "Find a number A divisble by 5 but not divisible by the nth prime, where n is the sum of As digits. " - an example answer could be "one could answer 10, which is divisible by 5, but 10 is also divisible by the 1+0=1 first prime number (2) and is thus not a valid solution

Comment: @Falco Out of 16 theoretical possibilities, 3 incorrect ones have already been proposed by other users as solutions. In each case I have commented in some detail upon their shortcomings.

Comment: @JMarcos Am I right that "contingent sentence" means that there must be at least one conifguration for pqr where the sentence yields true and at least one where the sentence yields false ?

Comment: @Falco Yes, that's the meaning of *contingent*: neither tautological nor antilogical.

Answer (score 5):

Question 1:

> `p implies NAND(q,r)`, which is equivalent to `(not p) or (not q) or (not r)` which is symmetric in the variables. Once you're told that the second gate is a NAND, you know the sentence must have the form `_ implies NAND(_,_)`. Since any permutation of `p,r,q` in the blanks is equivalent to the symmetric expression given, all possible choices are semantically equivalent. Intuitively, the sentence says that if a variable is true, the other two can't both also be true, which is equivalent to "It can't be the case that all three variables are true"

Comment: Nope, unfortunately this is not equivalent to the sentence *semantically characterized* by the statement of the problem. Anyway, you should try explaining *why* do you think this would be a solution to **Question 1**.

Comment: I edited in my reasoning. Maybe I'm just not understanding the problem.

Comment: Your intuition about symmetry is good, for it indeed would guarantee equivalence under permutation. However... there is *no* reason to think that the statement of the problem, up to **Question 1**, tells you that the second gate is a NAND, and there is no reason to think that the forgotten sentence resists permutation of its variables!

Comment: I upvoted your answer as a good attempt at a solution together with an explanation, even if it doesn't really solve the problem.

Comment: @JMarcos Then I don't know what your question is asking. When you asked for what the second gate was, I had understood that the conditions were specified knowing that gate. Otherwise, there are many different possibilities. By "semantically characterize", do you mean "character the set of assignments that make the formula true"?

Comment: Precisely: there are many different possibilities. However, when I ask you to *assume* that the information preceding **Question 1** is sufficient to determine (the equivalence class of) the  sentence, I have just given you an essential hint on how to drastically reduce your sample space and how to look for the solution!

Comment: @JMarcos Can you formally specify what that means? Or is this actually a lateral-thinking riddle?

Comment: Unfortunately, for this puzzle you will really have to reason only from what I have already told you. The hint is that you have to try understanding how in the world I could have *added information* by simply telling you that the sentence could be fully characterized in the paragraph preceding **Question 1**. In a sense, this way of adding extra info is similar to what happens to the muddy children involved in epistemic puzzles such as [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1909/who-has-mud-on-their-forehead/1915).

Answer (score 3):

I have a new answer based on a purely formal logical interpretation of the problem.

**Lemma 1:** The conditions in paragraph 1 do not specify a syntantically unique sentence.

**Proof of lemma:** Both the sentences `p implies (q or r)` and `p implies (q and r)` satisfying those conditions, as they have three atomic variables `p,q,r` and two connectives, one an implication implied by a variable. By, they are not logically equivalent as `p=True, q=True, r=False` satisfies the first but not the second.

Now, afterwards, we're asked to assume that  the previous information is sufficient to semantically characterize the forgotten sentence, which is the negation of Lemma 1. For having both Lemma 1 and its negation, we use the [principle of explosion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) to derive all statements.

Therefore, we derive that the forgotten statement was "I am the eggman, I am the walrus." As to the question of "the possible logical forms that my sentence could have had", it is the set of logical forms.

Comment: That was kind of fun. :) Anyway, what you have just confirmed is that these two sentences do not both belong to the class of solutions to the problem, and this is correct. Notice in any case that you have no reason to suppose even that implication is the leftmost connective in your expression! As a last comment, it is interesting to observe that both your sentences here could be used to give a solution to **Question 2** (even though, as we agreed, they cannot be both solutions to **Question 1**). Do you see why?

Answer (score 2):

I'll have a go with :

> $p \rightarrow (q \leftrightarrow r)$

together with

> $(p \rightarrow q) \leftrightarrow (p \rightarrow r)$

This reads as "p implies (q if and only if r)", and "(p implies q) if and only if (p implies r).

Comment: @JMarcos I pretty sure this is correct.  "if and only if" denotes logical equivalence.

Comment: That was a good try! (even though you have not justified where your sentence came from) However... note that, according to the statement of the problem, one would expect $p\to(q\leftrightarrow r)$ to be logically equivalent, for instance, to a sentence such as $q\leftrightarrow(p\to r)$ --- otherwise you cannot really say that the information I gave you was (necessary and) sufficient to warrant your conclusion about *this* being the forgotten sentence.

Comment: @JMarcos Oh, I see.  Very clever!  It's a nice question.  I'll give some more thought if I can find the time over the next day or two.  You asked : "... where your sentence came from".  I noticed that "implication" did not distribute over "and" and "or", so I scribbled around with the "biconditional" until I came up with my guess.

Comment: There are in principle 16 obvious candidates for the missing binary connective, of course, and one might surely give NAND or the biconditional a try. But a well-justified non-exhaustive-search solution to **Question 1** would be more elegant! (and it *is* available, depending on just a bit of algebraic manipulation)

Comment: @JMarcos Now I'm not sure if I understand your comment.  The sentence $ p \rightarrow (q \leftrightarrow r) $ is NOT logically equivalent to $ q \leftrightarrow (p \rightarrow r) $.  For example, they disagree when $ p, q, r $ are all false, or when $ p, q $ are false and $ r $ is true.

Comment: Precisely! They are *not* logically equivalent, but according to the statement of the problem **all you know** is that there is a variable (say, $p$) that is the antecedent of the implication. And this is the case in both sentences, isn't it? So, one would have expected the two sentences to be logically equivalent, right?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: As J Marcos points out in the comments, this answer cannot possibly be correct, as the 'lost sentence' it gives is tautological, not contingent as specified in the question.

It's been a while since I've done anything with formal logic, so please forgive (and correct) me if I butcher the terminology. I have only attempted to answer question 1.

Based on the information given there are three possible forms (up to relabeling of variables) for the forgotten sentence.

1. $p \rightarrow (q \text{ B } r)$
2. $(p \rightarrow q) \text{ B } r$
3. $p \text{ B }(q\rightarrow r)$

where B is some binary connective. Note that I left out $(p \text{ B } q) \rightarrow r$, as the implication doesn't have an atomic antecedent (unless B is also implication, in which case we're back in case 2).

There is no other information in the question that would allow us to choose any particular one of these forms over the others. Thus, the problem is only well-defined* if there is exactly one choice of B such that the three forms are semantically equivalent. As it happens, there is, and we can derive it as follows.

When $p$ is false, the three forms have the values $True$, $True\text{ B }r$, and $False\text{ B }(q\rightarrow r)$, respectively. These must all be equal regardless of the value of $r$, so $True\text{ B } True = True\text{ B }False = True$.

When $p$ is true and $q$ is false, form 1 reduces to $True \text{ B } True = True$ and form 2 to $False \text{ B } r$. Again these must be equal for either value of $r$, so $False \text{ B } True = False \text{ B } False = True$.

This is enough to completely characterize B: it is **the binary connective that always yields $True$ regardless of its operands**.

*I'm cheating a bit here, I think -- J Marcos only assumes that the information is enough to define the *sentence* up to semantic equivalence, which is not quite the same as  assuming the question "what was the other connective" has a well-defined answer. To make up the gap I'd need to show that semantic equivalence of $p \rightarrow (q \text{ C } r)$, $(p\rightarrow q)\text{ D } r$, and $p\text{ E }(q\rightarrow r)$ is enough to imply $\text{ C } = \text{ D } = \text{ E } = \text{ B }$, where B is the connective derived above. Proving this is completely mechanical (write down the truth tables for C, D, and E; plug in different values of $p$, $q$, and $r$ to 1, 2, and 3; and follow your nose) but would be tedious to write up, so I leave it as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Nice try. Some observations: (i) there are many more than three logical forms, but some may be discharged (still leaving more than three logical forms) as soon as you fix the variable in the antecedent of the mentioned implication; (2) you're not really cheating by postulating well-definedness, as that is indeed the effect of the *assumption* in the statement of the problem; (3) your solution cannot be correct, given the hypothesis that we're talking about a *contingent* sentence.

Comment: Could you give an example of a sentence with exactly two occurrences of (binary) connectives, one of which is implication, which doesn't fit into one of my given forms (ignoring a relabeling of variables)? Fair point about it being a contingent sentence, I missed that.

Comment: Relabelling of variables can transform a given sentence into a nonequivalent sentence (violating the assumed characterization of the forgotten sentence *up to logical equivalence*). I suggest you fix your antecedent, instead of fixing the order of the variables in the string. Sentences are not strings, anyway, but are rather structured as trees.

Comment: Just to be clear, is the answer to my question: "no, there isn't one"?

Comment: The problem is precisely that you cannot "ignore a relabeling of variables". That's why you're missing several logical forms.

Comment: Maybe I'm still missing something fundamental, but it seems to me I could write down all the relabelings, carry out the exact same reasoning, and it wouldn't change the substance of my answer one bit.

Comment: Look, there is more than one equivalence class that could solve the problem (depending, for instance, upon which specific variable you *fix* as the antecedent of the implication), each one of these classes containing several logical forms that respect the stipulations of the statement. Your sentences, however, do not all belong to the same class. Yet, a solution has to choose one of these classes to dwell on. There is really not much else I can say without doing the "tedious work" for you, or asking you to read again, with attention and patience, my recent comments on your endeavor.

Comment: I assure you I've read your comments carefully. I suspect either my misunderstanding is different (and probably deeper) than whatever you think it is, or that this puzzle is simply beyond my abilities.

Comment: You have come closer to a solution than anyone else. I firmly believe that it is not beyond your abilities.