# The king, the princess, the 3 wise men, and the 3 x's

Tags: logical-deduction

A princess just became of marriageable age, and her father went out to get 3 wise men. He placed them at a round table and wrote either an X or an O on each of their heads, writing in such a way that they could not feel it. In fact the king wrote an X on each of their heads, and said, "if you see at least one X, raise your hand". They all raised their hands. After an hour, the man in the middle said "I have an X on my head". How did he know?

Comment: Duplicate of [Who has mud on their forehead?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1909/who-has-mud-on-their-forehead) - the description is different, but the essential puzzle is the same.

Comment: How can a man be in the middle of a round table? Are the other two on the sides?